# Postgresql passwordcheck.c modification

Tags: c, postgresql

I need to modify the https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_5_13/contrib/passwordcheck/passwordcheck.c in order to check the password before set it.

I'm not very good with C.

So I added this check:

```
if (validuntil_null)
            ereport(ERROR,
                (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                 errmsg("password expiriration missing")));
```

and it works, it checks if the expiration date is set.

Now I want to check if this expiration date is reasonable, like no more than 3 months (using "validuntil_time") and if it is different from the previous set.

Any idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `extern bool TimestampDifferenceExceeds(TimestampTz start_time, TimestampTz stop_time,  int msec)` defined in postgres/inlcude/utils/timestamp.h?

Comment: This seems apropos:  https://www.sans.org/security-awareness-training/blog/time-password-expiration-die  As is this:  https://spycloud.com/new-nist-guidelines/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John, at the end I managed in that way:

```
if (validuntil_null) {
ereport(ERROR,
        (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                errmsg("password expiriration missing")));
} else {
TimestampTz now = GetCurrentTimestamp();
const off64_t threshold = (const off64_t)((off64_t)90 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 );
  if (now > validuntil_time) {
            ereport(ERROR,
                    (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                     errmsg("\nERROR now: %ld validuntil_time: %ld threshold: %ld",now,validuntil_time,threshold)));
  } else {
    const off64_t diff= (const off64_t)((off64_t)(validuntil_time - now)/1000);
    if (diff >= threshold) {
        ereport(ERROR,
                    (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                     errmsg("\nERROR: DATE is more than 90 days: now: %ld validuntil_time: %ld threshold: %ld",now,validuntil_time,threshold)));
    }
    elog(INFO,"\nnow: %ld validuntil_time: %ld threshold: %ld diff: %ld",now,validuntil_time,threshold,diff);
         }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the internals of PostgreSQL or the configuration of PostgreSQL.  My first approach would be to study the documentation to determine if it is possible to set a maximum password expiration time using the admin privileges.  I am guessing that you have studied that in detail already and feel that this is the best option.

Based on that, I did review some of the timestamp code in the Postgres github repository.  I have not compiled this, but believe this is close.  It was not clear to me what Datum is, whether that is already a TimeStampTz type, or if that needs to be converted in some way.  It might not compile properly without answering that question.  Let me know if this works for you:

At the top of the file, add this to the includes:

```
#include "utils/timestamp.h"
```

Later, at the same place where you placed your current code, replace your code with this:

```
if (validuntil_null) {
    ereport(ERROR,
            (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                    errmsg("password expiriration missing")));
} else {
    TimestampTz now = GetCurrentTimestamp();

    const int ThreeMonthsInMiliSeconds = 90 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
    if(TimestampDifferenceExceeds(now, validuntil_time, ThreeMonthsInMiliSeconds) {
        ereport(ERROR,
            (errcode(ERRCODE_INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE),
                errmsg("password expiriration time is greater than 90 days")));
    }
}
```

Here is the source code for that timedifference function from timestamp.c:

```
/*
 * TimestampDifferenceExceeds -- report whether the difference between two
 *      timestamps is >= a threshold (expressed in milliseconds)
 *
 * Both inputs must be ordinary finite timestamps (in current usage,
 * they'll be results from GetCurrentTimestamp()).
 */
bool
TimestampDifferenceExceeds(TimestampTz start_time,
                           TimestampTz stop_time,
                           int msec)
{
    TimestampTz diff = stop_time - start_time;

    return (diff >= msec * INT64CONST(1000));
}
```

Comment: Hi, the logic seems fine but how it calculates the date for the diff is pretty strange:the vale of now results 594223781391316, validuntil_time (Nov 1, 2018: 594345600000000), 3 months: 7776000000. So how to compare?

Comment: I changed the line:
const off_t ThreeMonthsInMiliSeconds = (const off_t)((off_t)90 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 );
due to overflow but it's not working, even with a 1 day difference it fails, with the past it works:
# ALTER USER regress_user1 PASSWORD 'a_nice_long_password' VALID UNTIL 'Oct 30 2018';
ERROR:  password expiriration time is greater than 90 days

# ALTER USER regress_user1 PASSWORD 'a_nice_long_password' VALID UNTIL 'Nov 1 2017';
ALTER ROLE

Comment: I added a copy of the source code for the timestamp.c function if that helps.